# Upload picture using Selenium JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to create automation to upload picture, using Selenium with this script:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(`avatar-upload`)).sendKeys(`/home/user/Desktop/smg935-0hero-0930.jpeg`)
```

It return to:

```
ElementNotInteractableError: Element <input id="avatar-upload" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

[image]

Comment: If element is not visible, you cannot upload image like that

Comment: Why don't you try the same scenario with webDriverWait.

Comment: @cruisepandey element has `style : display-none` , so WebDriverWait won't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the element is not visible, you can't interact with it from UI, like `sendKeys`. One approach is change the element attribute in background way through calling HTML DOM API

```
let upload_ele = driver.findElement(By.id('avatar-upload'))
let file_path = '/home/user/Desktop/smg935-0hero-0930.jpeg'

driver.executeScript('return arguments[0].value=arguments[1];', upload_ele, file_path)
```

There is a disadvantage of this approach, because it act in background, so it won't 
trigger key/mouse events which bind to the element. If the upload widget listen on key event to detect user choose file or not, before user can continue click upload button. In such case the background approach won't work.

Comment: May be this works, but it doesn't UI testing anymore

Comment: Yes, I agree with your point. Unless his upload widget supply another visible input box to accept the file path by `sendKeys`, he have to use background approach or click some element to open the `File Choose` Dialog to choose file which is more difficulty to automation.

Comment: I try the code it return JavascriptError: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Comment: (node:21020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JavascriptError: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/user/Selenium/belajar/sinau3/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/user/Selenium/belajar/sinau3/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:542:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/user/Selenium/belajar/sinau3/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)

Comment: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:21020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21020) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Did you run script with Selenium IDE? and Which browser you used. Please try on Chrome.

Comment: In Firefox browser , okey i will try on Chrome